# Mutli dimensional nested list comprehesion and its python, numpy equivalents

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I recently discovered that I can use nested list comprehensions to evaluate an expression for parameter combinations and save the result as an array:

```
M = np.array(

[ [ [ expression
    for c in C ]
  for b in B ]
for a in A ]

)
```

where `A,B,C` are the parameters to be iterated over and `expression` is an expression evaluated with `a,b,c` (for example `a+b+c`)

M will then be an array with dimension `(len(A),len(B),len(C))`

Is there a simple way to accomplish this without using a nested list comprehension ?

I'm looking for a solution that will be more self-explanatory, as a nested list comprehension might not be very readable and confusing for someone who encounters it in code. Take another example of a nested list comprehension

```
M = np.array(
[
expression
for c in C
    for b in B
        for a in A
]
)
```

Here, M will be a flat, `len(A)*len(B)*len(C)` dimensional array. This can be "simplified" to:

```
import itertools as it
M = np.array( [expression for a,b,c in it.product(A,B,C)] )
```

Is there a similar solution for the problem above?

Thanks.

Here is a specific example with inputs and an expression. P is a function that evaluates parameters a,b or c. Here, it doesn't actually do anything useful.

```
A, B, C = np.arange(3), np.arange(4), np.arange(5)
P = lambda *args: sum(args[0][args[1]]*((len(args)>1) or rand()))

M = np.array(

[ [ [ mean( [P(X, a, b) > P(X, c) for X in rand(10,10,10)])
    for c in C ]
  for b in B ]
for a in A ]

)
```

Comment: Do you have any specific question?

Comment: sorry, I accidentally submitted the question before completing it. edit now.

Comment: I edited the question to illustrate a general case, the posted answer is helpful for in the simplest case only (like a+b+c). I'm looking forward to more answers.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, yes you can do this by converting A, B and C into numpy arrays and then using broadcasting to do things in one step. For example

```
import numpy as np
A, B, C = np.arange(3), np.arange(4), np.arange(5)
result = A[..., None, None] +  B[None, ..., None] + C[None, None, ...]
```

which in this case gives me

```
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]],

       [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]])
```

If you can give a specific example (inputs, expected outputs and example expression) then I can make the answer more specific.

More on broadcasting:

- http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/numpy.html#broadcasting
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: I specified an example expression in the question. for a very simple example, take your inputs and replace `expression` with `a+b+c`.I am looking for a general answer however, meaning that `expression` can take any valid form

Comment: Well the general answer is it depends. Most NumPy functions and simple operations will work. With these questions it is always best to provide concrete examples.

Comment: I edited the question, to provide a concrete example, thanks.